# Tensorflow can't find GPU in TF 2.16.1

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Apologies on yet another TF can't find GPU question. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10 and a new conda environment like so:

```
conda create --name tf anaconda
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

Install log indicates that TF was successfully installed:

```
Successfully installed absl-py-2.1.0 astunparse-1.6.3 flatbuffers-24.3.7 gast-0.5.4 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.62.1 h5py-3.10.0 keras-3.1.1 libclang-18.1.1 ml-dtypes-0.3.2 namex-0.0.7 nvidia-cublas-cu12-12.3.4.1 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12-12.3.101 nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12-12.3.107 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12-12.3.107 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12-12.3.101 nvidia-cudnn-cu12-8.9.7.29 nvidia-cufft-cu12-11.0.12.1 nvidia-curand-cu12-10.3.4.107 nvidia-cusolver-cu12-11.5.4.101 nvidia-cusparse-cu12-12.2.0.103 nvidia-nccl-cu12-2.19.3 nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12-12.3.101 opt-einsum-3.3.0 optree-0.10.0 tensorboard-2.16.2 tensorboard-data-server-0.7.2 tensorflow-2.16.1 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.36.0 termcolor-2.4.0
```

According to [TF change log](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases), TF 2.16.1 was built against cuda 12.3, which is what I have:

```
Mon Mar 25 21:54:08 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.29.06              Driver Version: 545.29.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA Graphics Device         Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8              10W / 285W |     11MiB / 16376MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1157      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, TF can't find any devices. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Python 3.11.7 (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:12:31) [GCC 11.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
2024-03-25 21:59:36.637049: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-03-25 21:59:36.666269: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI AVX512_BF16 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-25 21:59:37.111197: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

In [2]: tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
Out[2]: True

In [3]: print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
2024-03-25 21:59:57.607478: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-03-25 21:59:57.608189: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

This is a known bug in TF 2.16.1. See comments for solution.

Comment: Do you have the correct `cuDNN` version installed?

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue with TF 2.16.1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63362#issuecomment-2016019354

Comment: @stevew nvidia-smi does not show the installed version of CUDA, only the highest possible version supported by the GPU driver.
Nevertheless, the log shows that the installed CUDA versions are compatible. check the paths under which the various packages are installed. sometimes exporting the path is enough. Is your Ubuntu on WSL?

Comment: I've solved it by following the steps in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63362#issuecomment-2016019354 . TF 2.16.1 did not correct set the path of cuda / cudnn